# Querying Windows Azure Storage Table in Azure Data Lake Analytics U-SQL

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have found documentation for querying files from Azure Data Lake Storage or Azure Storage Blob with EXTRACT FROM as well as SQL, Azure SQL Database or Azure Data Warehouse with external tables in a data source location. However, I cannot find anything referring to Azure Table Storage.

We have data in table storage that is accessed in its raw form, plus a requirement to carry out an aggregation over this data for which Azure Data Lake Analytics appears to be ideal, but I'm not keen on having to go via an Data Lake Storage / Azure Storage Blobs intermediary flat file.

Is there a way to query data directly from Azure Table Storage?

Comment: Can you please expand the WAST, ADLS, WASB, ADLA acronyms?

Comment: Yes, sorry! WAST = Windows Azure Storage Table, ADLS = Azure Data Lake Storage, WASB = Windows Azure Storage Blob, ADLA = Azure Data Lake Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAST (Windows Azure Table Storage) is currently not directly supported. You would have to use ADF to transfer the data from WAST to ADLS.

Please file a request with your scenario at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback if you want us to consider adding support. Please also let us know if you need us to support the flexible column set capabilities or if a fixed schema over the table store would be sufficient.

Thanks
Michael